# How to install postgis 1.5 in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: postgresql, dependencies, postgis, ubuntu-14.04, apt

The problem is that my project uses old postgres and postgis versions. In 13.04 I just downloaded [deb](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/postgresql-8.4-postgis) packet and installed it,but it looks like something changed in 14.04 and packet doesn't seem to resolve any of it's dependencies.

Do you have any ideas how it can be fixed?

Comment: Looks like you already asked this here: http://askubuntu.com/q/526657/75715 . Please pick one and delete the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that [PostGIS 1.5 is supported for PostgreSQL versions 8.3 to 9.2](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS), but the standard install for Ubuntu 14.04 is [PostgreSQL 9.3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/postgresql), so you need to install an older version.

I suggest installing PostgreSQL 9.2 from the [PGDG APT repo](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt), which is carefully maintained.

After installing an older version of PostgreSQL, you will probably need to build PostGIS 1.5 from source. Here are the perquisites:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgeos-c1 libproj-dev libjson-c-dev libxml2-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc docbook-xsl docbook-mathml
```

And the download, configure, build, and install:

```
wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-1.5.8.tar.gz
tar xfvz postgis-1.5.8.tar.gz
cd postgis-1.5.8
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

Also see [these build instructions for an older version of Ubuntu](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS15Ubuntu1004src).

Comment: It worked. I'm not really into installing packages from sources, so great thanks! P.S. also, I had to install `libgeos-dev` and `postgresql-server-dev-8.4`

Comment: Worked great on Ubuntu 15 with PostgreSQL 9.1.

Comment: Where should be installed? And once it is installed, how can I do "create extension postgis"?

Comment: `create extension postgis` was introduced for PostGIS 2.0, so for 1.5 you need to either create a template or use enabler scripts.